# Custom Reg file with keys not present on registry

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry

I created my own registry file, using personal keys to set up my windows, but what I didnt know is that some of these keys are not present in a fresh install of windows, and when I try to use it does not import saying the key selected is invalid, I am assuming the reason its because some of the keys dont even exist, is there a way for add keys to all my regfile, or I have to manually look for each one missing? and add the command necessary.

Hope it makes sense,
Thanks !

```
; Classic Control Panel / Hide Action Center Icon
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"ForceClassicControlPanel"=dword:00000001
"HideSCAHealth"=dword:00000000

; Disable Action Center / Security Center Service
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wscsvc]
"Start"=dword:00000004

; Windows update + Plus VBS script
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000001
"IncludeRecommendedUpdates"=dword:00000001

; UAC Disabled: 0
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableVirtualization"=dword:00000001
"EnableInstallerDetection"=dword:00000001
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:00000001
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
"EnableSecureUIAPaths"=dword:00000001
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000005
"ValidateAdminCodeSignatures"=dword:00000000
"EnableUIADesktopToggle"=dword:00000000
"EnableCursorSuppression"=dword:00000001
"ConsentPromptBehaviorUser"=dword:00000003
"dontdisplaylastusername"=dword:00000000
"legalnoticecaption"=""
"legalnoticetext"=""
"scforceoption"=dword:00000000
"shutdownwithoutlogon"=dword:00000001
"undockwithoutlogon"=dword:00000001
"FilterAdministratorToken"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Audit]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI\Clipboard]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI\Clipboard\ExceptionFormats]
"CF_UNICODETEXT"=dword:0000000d
"CF_DIBV5"=dword:00000011
"CF_PALETTE"=dword:00000009
"CF_BITMAP"=dword:00000002
"CF_TEXT"=dword:00000001
"CF_DIB"=dword:00000008
"CF_OEMTEXT"=dword:00000007

; Taskbar Settings
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2]
"Settings"=hex:28,00,00,00,ff,ff,ff,ff,03,02,00,00,03,00,00,00,3e,00,00,00,1e,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,1a,04,00,00,80,07,00,00,38,04,00,00

; Show all icons on notification tray
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"EnableAutoTray"=dword:00000000

; Files Explorer Settins
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"Start_SearchFiles"=dword:00000002
"ServerAdminUI"=dword:00000000
"Hidden"=dword:00000001
"ShowCompColor"=dword:00000001
"HideFileExt"=dword:00000000
"DontPrettyPath"=dword:00000000
"ShowInfoTip"=dword:00000001
"HideIcons"=dword:00000000
"MapNetDrvBtn"=dword:00000000
"WebView"=dword:00000001
"Filter"=dword:00000000
"ShowSuperHidden"=dword:00000000
"SeparateProcess"=dword:00000000
"AutoCheckSelect"=dword:00000000
"IconsOnly"=dword:00000000
"ShowTypeOverlay"=dword:00000001
"ShowStatusBar"=dword:00000001
"ListviewAlphaSelect"=dword:00000001
"ListviewShadow"=dword:00000001
"TaskbarAnimations"=dword:00000001
"StartMenuInit"=dword:00000006
"ReindexedProfile"=dword:00000001
"StoreAppsOnTaskbar"=dword:00000001
"TaskbarSizeMove"=dword:00000000
"DisablePreviewDesktop"=dword:00000001
"TaskbarSmallIcons"=dword:00000001
"TaskbarGlomLevel"=dword:00000000
"DontUsePowerShellOnWinX"=dword:00000001
"Start_JumpListItems"=dword:00000000
"Start_TrackProgs"=dword:00000000
"Start_TrackDocs"=dword:00000000

; Disable Charms Bar and the Apps Switcher 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI] 
"DisableCharmsHint"=dword:00000001 
"DisableTRcorner"=dword:00000001 
"DisableTLcorner"=dword:00000001

; Go to the Desktop instead of Start when I Sign in 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage] 

; Show Desktop Background as Start Screen Background 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent] 
"MotionAccentId_v1.00"=dword:000000db  
"OpenAtLogon"=dword:00000000

; List Desktop Apps First in the Apps View when it's Sorted by Category 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage] 

; Don't Replace Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell On the WinX Menu 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] 
"DontUsePowerShellOnWinX"=dword:00000001   
"DesktopFirst"=dword:00000001  

; Disable Backup for Windows 8.1 Apps 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\SettingSync] 

; Turn off The Let Me Teach You About Metro Tutorial Tips
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI]
"DisableHelpSticker"=dword:00000001
"EnableBackupForWin8Apps"=dword:00000000 

; Windows border sizes
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"SmCaptionWidth"="-330"
"BorderWidth"="0"
"PaddedBorderWidth"="0"

; Remote Desktop ON
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server]
"AllowRemoteRPC"=dword:00000001
"fDenyTSConnections"=dword:00000000

; Disable System Restore
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\SystemRestore]
"DisableConfig"=dword:00000001
"DisableSR"=dword:00000001

; Disable Windows Indexer
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WSearch]
"Start"=dword:00000004

; File Associations
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.nfo]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.nfo\OpenWithList]
"a"="WORDPAD.EXE"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.nfo\OpenWithProgids]
"MSInfoFile"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.nfo\UserChoice]
"Hash"="glusomgmk+s="
"ProgId"="Applications\\wordpad.exe"

; SmartScreen OFF
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"SmartScreenEnabled"="Off"

; Command prompt Here.
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Open Command Prompt Here\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"

; Disable Hibernate
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power]
"HibernateEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So LPChip your reply made me try one key separably from the others and still did not work, but I found my issue.

The reason it did not work was because I did not include the line below at the start of my reg file

"Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00"

After I added that line it worked just fine without any issue, sorry I feel so dumb!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An invalid key means that you made a typo somewhere. Even if a key doesn't exist, you can add it anyway.

Do note that different OS versions have different versions of the registry. So a registry key for Windows 7 appears different than for Windows 8. A regfile made for windows 7 should work for windows 8, but not the other way around.